# Google assistant watch movie action for embedded youtube video

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-home, google-assist-api

When a user says "Hey google play David's video on TV". I would like google to open a url on my website which has a youtube video embedded and start playing it on the smart TV. I can't see what kinds of media are supported from the docs. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for posting, David! That feature is not currently supported.

Comment: Thanks @Max Wiederholt I'de like to integrate https://www.crowdform.co.uk/hntv/live with google assistant somehow - could you suggest a way I could do this?